# Can we make a prediction model in WEKA?

Tags: model, weka, prediction

I am trying to build a prediction model using WEKA. For example, I plan to build a model for classifying whether something is leading to A or P using Database 1. I will then use another Testing and Training dataset to predict outcomes whether something is A or B using this model. Are there any prediction packages for that? I saw Forecasting packages but that is for numeric data. I am looking prediction packages that could help me classify data and make predictions. Also, can I save this model and make it publicly available so that others can use it as well and make similar predictions? Is this possible in WEKA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can make predictions with a model. Since it is not clear, whether you want to do that from the command-line, in the GUI or from code, I recommend you have a look at the following Weka wiki article:

https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/making_predictions/

If you want to use the API, check the articles listed here:

https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/using_the_api/

Also, every Weka installation comes with code examples, aptly named *wekaexamples.zip*.